# Rails 4 using namespaced classes or configuring autoloading for subfolders, which to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So in Rails we can use for classes||modules in subfolders of defaultly autoloaded folders, namespaces like: `ContractServices::Approval` which Rails will get from for example in `app/services/contract_services/approval.rb`, BUT we'll have to name that class as `ContractServices::Approval` for Rails to find it.

Also we can autoload that subfolder path- via `config.autoload_paths`, so we can use simply `Approval` for that mentioned class name.

Either will work, but what is the better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you're putting a bunch of things in a subdirectory it's because you recognize that they are logically separate from the things in the parent directory **and** they are related logically to each other. Those are also compelling criteria for when it's a good idea to namespace something in ruby/rails too.

The other thing that factors into this is practicality, the more "top-level" autoloaded directories you have, the more constants (ie. class names) you will have in the global namespace, and therefore the higher the risk of a name clash. Ie. if you have `::Approval` being autoloaded because you've put `app/services/contract_services` into `autoload_paths` and then sometime later you create `app/services/approval.rb` - your filesystem will let you create it, because there's no clash with the file in the subdirectory, and ruby won't care that you have one class that is later reopened elsewhere, so you have what could be a difficult to debug namespace clash.

The real answer to your question is that no, there's not a widely accepted best practice for this, and Rails itself autoloads `app/models/concerns` into the global namespace (although at least they're modules, so you'll get an error if there is a module <-> class name clash). Even my reasoning above is only really relevant if you've got a largish app and/or largish team of committers.